# Cual sería esta expresion regular?

Tags: regex

Cómo sería una expresión regular que comprenda números hasta el 2147483647 (máximo int)

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Hola Luis, ¿Has intentado algo hasta ahora? ¿Que problemas has tenido? te invito a pasar por [ask] para ver como elaborar una respuesta de calidad y que esta sea bien recibida. De todas formas, te recomendaría buscar en Google, aprenderás más que si te lo responden directamente.

Comment: Por qué una expresión regular, si un simple if es suficiente? Alguna razón en especial?

Comment: Mi profesor ha mandado eso

Comment: Prueba con `.+`.

Comment: Luis: por favor indica qué has intentado. Si no, ¿cómo vas a aprender? Piensa que en el examen solo estaréis el profesor y tú ;-)

Comment: No sólo no aportas que has hecho para intentar dar con la solución, sino que para más inri te ríes de la propuesta de otro compañero, tenga o no tenga errores. Por eso he votado negativo a esta pregunta.

Answer (score 4):

Debido a que las expresiones regulares trabajan con texto establecer un intervalo numérico no es algo trivial.

La expresión regular que se utiliza para reconocer un número entre 0 y 9 es `[0-9]` por lo que si se desea reconocer un intervalo mayor se emplearan combinaciones de expresiones como la anterior.

Partiendo de un caso más simple como reconocer números en un rango del 0 al 125 podemos observar que la expresión regular empleada debería reconocer número del 0 al 99 de forma base siguiendo la siguiente expresión `[0-9][0-9]?` (donde la interrogación representa encontrar 0 o 1 elementos del intervalo) y después añadir la condición que nos permitirá obtener el intervalo de 100 a 125 con la siguiente expresión `1[0-2][0-5]` en este caso no añadimos un símbolo `?` ya que queremos obligar a que todos los símbolos aparezcan.

Siguiendo este razonamiento, para hallar un valor entre el 0 y el 2147483647 debería ser:

`\b([0-9]|[1-8][0-9]|9[0-9]|[1-8][0-9]{2}|9[0-8][0-9]|99[0-9]|[1-8][0-9]{3}|9[0-8][0-9]{2}|99[0-8][0-9]|999[0-9]|[1-8][0-9]{4}|9[0-8][0-9]{3}|99[0-8][0-9]{2}|999[0-8][0-9]|9999[0-9]|[1-8][0-9]{5}|9[0-8][0-9]{4}|99[0-8][0-9]{3}|999[0-8][0-9]{2}|9999[0-8][0-9]|99999[0-9]|[1-8][0-9]{6}|9[0-8][0-9]{5}|99[0-8][0-9]{4}|999[0-8][0-9]{3}|9999[0-8][0-9]{2}|99999[0-8][0-9]|999999[0-9]|[1-8][0-9]{7}|9[0-8][0-9]{6}|99[0-8][0-9]{5}|999[0-8][0-9]{4}|9999[0-8][0-9]{3}|99999[0-8][0-9]{2}|999999[0-8][0-9]|9999999[0-9]|[1-8][0-9]{8}|9[0-8][0-9]{7}|99[0-8][0-9]{6}|999[0-8][0-9]{5}|9999[0-8][0-9]{4}|99999[0-8][0-9]{3}|999999[0-8][0-9]{2}|9999999[0-8][0-9]|99999999[0-9]|1[0-9]{9}|20[0-9]{8}|21[0-3][0-9]{7}|214[0-6][0-9]{6}|2147[0-3][0-9]{5}|21474[0-7][0-9]{4}|214748[0-2][0-9]{3}|2147483[0-5][0-9]{2}|21474836[0-3][0-9]|214748364[0-7])\b`.

Los símbolos `\b` al principio y al final sirven para que la expresión solo acepte números entre espacios o caracteres que no sean ni letras ni otros números. Si lo que quisieras es parsear un input cuyo valor solo pudiera ser el de un número en ese rango entonces deberías emplear los siguientes símbolos: `^(expresión)$`.

PD: La solución no es mía, la he obtenido de la siguiente página:
http://gamon.webfactional.com/regexnumericrangegenerator/

Comment: No soy un experto en expresiones regulares y es muy posible que haya una solución mejor pero es lo que se me ha ocurrido a mi, un saludo.

Comment: Me he permitido editar tu respuesta porque estaba todo el texto muy junto y era difícil de leer. Espero que no te importe :)

Comment: @Pikoh sin problema! Muchas gracias.

Comment: Buena respuesta. Comentar solo que muchas implementaciones de expresiones regulares permiten indicar el número de repeticiones de elementos con llaves; así por ejemplo `[0-9]{3,}` sería "3 o más repeticiones de [0-9]" y `[0-9]{3,6}` sería "entre 3 ó 6 repeticiones de [0-9]".

Comment: @SJuan76 tiene todo el sentido, de hecho mientras respondia la pregunta me preguntaba si eso existía, gracias por la aportación.

Comment: No acepta `1999999999` (entre otros), que es un número correcto. No puedes limitar tan alegremente el máximo de número en cada posición porque éstos dependen de todo el conjunto del número

Comment: Algunos ejemplos de números que no hacen match (pero deberían) https://regex101.com/r/iGrYXs/1/

Comment: @Julio Tienes razón, he estado comprobándolo y el caso es mucho más complejo, actualizo con la solución correcta. Un saludo.

Comment: Bien hecho. Creo que podrías simplificarla eliminando todas las comprobaciones con los nueves `99999...` y en su lugar utilizar `1?[0-9]{0,9}` Así queda más compacta: https://regex101.com/r/iGrYXs/2/

Comment: @Julio En efecto, queda bastante más claro así, el único problema en ese caso sería que acepta ceros delante del número lo cual podría o no considerarse un error en función del objetivo de la expresión. Aun así buena solución, enhorabuena.

Comment: Bien visto, si no se quisieran los ceros se podría solucionar con un lookahead negativo. https://regex101.com/r/iGrYXs/3/